# Reading integers from AppSettings over and over

Tags: web-config, appsettings

Some I do quite a lot of is read integers from AppSettings. What's the best way to do this?

Rather than do this every time:

```
int page_size; 
if (int.TryParse( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAGE_SIZE"], out page_size){

}
```

I'm thinking a method in my `Helpers` class like this:

```
int GetSettingInt(string key) { 
  int i;
  return int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key], out i) ? i : -1;
}
```

but this is just to save some keystrokes.

Ideally, I'd love to put them all into some kind of structure that I could use intellisense with so I don't end up with run-time errors, but I don't know how I'd approach this... or if this is even possible.

What's a best practices way of getting and reading integers from the AppSettings section of the Web.Config?

**ONE MORE THING...**

wouldn't it be a good idea to set this as `readonly`?

`readonly int pageSize = Helpers.GetSettingInt("PAGE_SIZE")` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've found an answer to my problem. It involves extra work at first, but in the end, it will reduce errors.

It is found at [Scott Allen's blog OdeToCode](http://odetocode.com/code/345.aspx) and here's my implementation:

Create a static class called `Config`

```
public static class Config {

   public static int PageSize {
       get { return int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAGE_SIZE"]); }
   }
   public static int HighlightedProductId {
     get { 
      return int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HIGHLIGHT_PID"]); 
     }
   }
}
```

Advantage of doing this are three-fold:

- Intellisense
- One breakpoint (DRY)
- Since I only am writing the Config String ONCE, I do a regular int.Parse.

If someone changes the AppSetting Key, it will break, but I can handle that, as those values aren't changed and the performance is better than a `TryParse` and it can be fixed in one location.

The solution is so simple... I don't know why I didn't think of it before. Call the values like so:

```
Config.PageSize

Config.HighlightedProductId
```

Yay!

Comment: While this does seem to be the best way of handling this particular problem, I don't know that you can call this DRY. Every new integer you add requires both a `Web.Config` key and a `Config` class property.

If you don't need the power of the `Web.Config` transforms (unlikely, cause they're useful), you could put them all directly in the Config/Constants class, and skip the need to int.Parse()

Comment: What if the user puts a string in the app setting?  This would throw an exception, and there is no exception handling or default setting.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question was asked many years ago, but maybe this answer could be useful for someone. Currently, if you're already receiving an `IConfiguration` reference in your class constructor, the best way to do it is using `GetValue<int>("appsettings-key-goes-here")`:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        int value = _configuration.GetValue<int>("appsettings-key-goes-here");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [T4Config](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T4Config/). I will generate an interface and concrete implementation of your appsettings and connectionstringsections of you web/app config using Lazyloading of the values in the proper data types. It uses a simple T4 template to auto generate things for you.